# Как хранить диапазоны значений?

Tags: c#

В `Excel`-файле хранятся диапазоны значений. Если входное значение в промежутке между `0` и `200`, то на выходе мы должны получить `0,28`. Хранить это все предполагаю в `Dictionary`, но не совсем понятно как реализовать сравнение.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А если значение между 1.000 и 10.000, то что мы должны получить? 0,28 или 0,26?

Comment: А при чём тут Excel? какая разница, откуда берутся значения?

Comment: @XelaNimed 0.26

Comment: Загружаете пары (граница-значение) в массив, и сравниваете входное с границей в цикле. Если меньше [или равно] - запомнить значение в переменную, иначе бряк из цикла. И использовать то, что в переменной. Т.е. в массиве будет `(200, 0.28);(1000,0.26);...`

Comment: Как будет выглядеть Ваш словарь?

Comment: @Akina а еще лучше бинарным поиском, массив-то все равно отсортирован.

Comment: @trollingchar Ой, да что там того массива? накладных расходов на бин-поиск получится больше, чем профиту.

Comment: @Akina ну для 9 элементов и правда смысла нет